# Solr sint type limit

Tags: tomcat, solr, schema, catalina

i've this schema:

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</field>
```

and when i try to push a new doc with id = 6661883440, i get this error:

> SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=6661883440] Error adding field 'id'='6661883440'
>
> Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error while creating field 'id{type=sint,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,sortMissingLast, required=true}' from value '6661883440'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6661883440"

There are some limits on the sint type field? Any advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [int](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieIntField.html) field in Solr is `A numeric field that can contain 32-bit signed two's complement integer values`.

```
Min Value Allowed: -2147483648
Max Value Allowed: 2147483647
```

Use [Long](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieLongField.html) which is `A numeric field that can contain 64-bit signed two's complement integer values`.

```
Min Value Allowed: -9223372036854775808
Max Value Allowed: 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Tnx, u've resolved my issue. ;) I've tried to find some specifics about the fields type but without success. Tnx a lot.